# Adding new fields to custom objects in managed package

Tags: managed-package, security, custom-field

I am a newbie to salesforce and still evaluating the platform for building products.
The product needs to be sold as a managed package.

The product many need to be customized by the clients to suit their exact purpose. E.g. Adding additional fields to a custom object to store data, and display it on the pages. Is that possible with managed packages?

Also, is there a way to control which objects can be extended by adding fields?

Comment: Good answer below, indeed its a fundamental feature of the product to be able to extend managed objects with new fields in the subscriber org, but critically not change them. On your second question, while Setup access is a permission, its not at the object scope, i'm wondering what your motive for wanting to constrain this per object is out of interest? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, custom fields can be added to objects in a managed package. No, you can't restrict an administrator's ability to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Custom fields can be added to the objects with a managed package namespace from within a subscriber org.

The publisher of the package can't prevent admin users in the subscriber org from adding custom fields, but the publisher could include a trigger on your custom object that detects unexpected fields at runtime and causes DML to fail or politely notifies admin users that adding fields is unsupported via email, for example.

Wanting to restrict the creation of custom fields within a subscriber org could be a sign of an architectural flaw.  Maybe a protected Custom Setting object would be more appropriate.